# Does $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} (1 + x)^{\ln x}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

> Does $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} (1 + x)^{\ln x}$ exist?

I do not have any attempts solving it because I do not know how to transform it into the form in which I use l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: **Hint :** $$(1+x)^{\ln(x)} = \exp(\ln(x)\ln(1+x))$$ and $\ln(x)\ln(1+x) \sim x \ln(x) \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there's a limit, say
$$
L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} (1 + x)^{\ln x}. 
$$
Apply the natural logarithm, and note that $u \mapsto \ln u$ is continuous, so we can pass the limit through the logarithm:
\begin{align}
\ln L &= \ln \biggl(\, \lim_{x \to 0^+} (1 + x)^{\ln x} \biggr) \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln \Bigl( (1 + x)^{\ln x} \Bigr) \\[4pt]
&= \lim_{x \to 0^+} (\ln x) \ln (1 + x) \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln (1 + x)}{(\ln x)^{-1}}
\end{align}
which is indeterminate of the form $\frac{0}{0}$. You can now apply l'Hôpital's rule and assuming that this converges, then you can recover the original limit by exponentiating
$$
L = e^{\ln L}.
$$